# List<String> to List<Object> C#

Tags: c#, .net, list

I've googled and seen conversions to `List<Object>`. But I think my case is different. I have the following:

```
public class Entry
{
    [XmlText]
    public string DataLogEntry { get; set; }
}
```

and used like this:

```
public class EndLot
{
    [XmlElement("Entry")]
    public List<Entry> Items;
}
```

So if I have list of strings ie.

```
List<string> EndLotLines
```

How can I create an instance of `EndLot` with this list. Am trying to:

```
List<Entry> Items =  (List<Entry>)EndLotLines;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Linq's [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) method:

```
var items = EndLotLines.Select(s => new Entry { DataLogEntry = s }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to create new `Entry` instances from each string.  Would it make sense to write this?

```
Entry e = (Entry)"whatever";
```

No.  You can use:

```
Items = EndLotLines.Select(s => new Entry { DataLogEntry = s }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var endLot = new EndLot
{
   Items = EndLotLines.Select(e => new Entry { DataLogEntry = e }).ToList();
};
```